# A formula error for a simple IF statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a statement as simple as this for my Excel sheet:

```
=IF(C2=”Yes”,1,2)
```

But I am getting the following error:

[image]

Does it have to do with language settings? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: change the `”` to the appropriate: `"`

Comment: And your Excel might also require `;` instead of `,`.

Comment: @ScottCraner Does not seem to work.

Comment: @BigBen That did the trick. Does this apply to all commas?

Comment: https://exceljet.net/glossary/list-separator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have typed that formula inside my Excel, and I got errors until I changed into this:

```
=IF(C2="Yes";1;2)
```

As you see, no curly double quotes but standard ones. And as a separator I have used semi-colons instead of commas.

However this might be due to locale settings: start with the double quotes and proceed from there.